# Layer of roads segments with attribute "STEL" by rsd.cz NDIC

Tags: road, traffic, czech-republic

Is it possible download layer with attribute "STEL"?

Attribute means segments of roads in Czech republic created by "ŘSD", more information at this [link](https://www.rsd.cz/wps/portal/).

"STEL" attribute is using for visualization NDIC data, more informations about NDIC are at this [link](http://registr.dopravniinfo.cz/en/providers/cz-ndic/).

Documentation for NDIC (english language):

[link](http://registr.dopravniinfo.cz/docs/x-format/cz-ndic_ddr-common-v3.2.5-en.pdf)

Documentation for NDIC (czech language):

[link](https://portal.dopravniinfo.cz/public/files/userfiles/Rozhrani_DDR_v3.2.5.pdf)

Comment: If it’s open data that you seek then I think the place to ask is the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: Thank you for you comment, OpenData is now for me, I will writte there.